# WSO2 api manager: Invalid login credentials when i try to use a tenant user in publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

**My issue is this**
I add a tenant test.com with a username admin@test.com
I logged in in api publisher

> "Error! Login failed. Please recheck the username and password and try
> again.."

I try to login to management console and it was successful.
I am using same database for user.
I have a separate setup for publisher, store and management console

Here is my diagram

[image]

Comment: The last line will be more clear if you can show your architecture/deployment diagram.

Comment: @Bee i added my diagram

Comment: Have you shared the userstore among these?

Comment: @Bee yes..
I think i know what the cause

Comment: in my api-manager.xml file for publisher
i was pointing the AuthManager -> serverURL to my identity provider
after changing it to my carbon management console i was able to login
hmm. that's weird